# low level JAVASCRIPT, cant return a picture value with variable X

Tags: javascript

So basically I am making a menu and every time the user clicks on a select option, the image of his meal choice appears. I want to also make my function return the price of the item when the option is selected. My pictures work on select, but my "demo" will not change to the value of the item and I need help from you guys.

```
    <select name="entree" id="entree" onChange="changeit(this.value)">
        <option value="hidden" selected>Choisir...</option>
        <option value="salade">Salade</option>
        <option value="escargot">Escargot</option>
      </select><br />
    <img id="imgselect" src="" alt="demo"/>
    <h3 id= "demo1"></h3>

    <select name="entree" id="entree" onChange="changerepas(this.value)">
        <option value="hidden1" selected>Choisir...</option>
        <option value="spaghetti">Spaghetti</option>
        <option value="lasagne">Lasagne</option>
      </select>
    <br />
    <img id="imgselect1" src="" alt="demo"/>
    <h3 id="demo"></h3>





function changeit(option) {
    var image;
    var price;

    switch (option) {
    case "salade":
        image = "salade.jpg";
        price = "5.95$";
        break;
    case "escargot":
        image = "escargot.jpg";
        price = "4.95$";
        break;
    case "hidden":
        image = "vile.jpg";
        price = "";
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    document.getElementById("imgselect").setAttribute("src", image);
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = price;
}
 function changerepas(option) {
    var image;
    var price;

    switch (option) {
    case "spaghetti":
        image = "spaghetti.jpg";
        price = "8.95$";
        break;
    case "lasagne":
        image = "lasagne.jpg";
        price = "9.95$";
        break;
    case "hidden1":
        image = "vide.jpg";
        price = "";
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    document.getElementById("imgselect1").setAttribute("src", image);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = price;
}
```

Comment: I declared x as the id "demo1", but when I select an option, it will just make the demo disappear, and not make the price appear, also, did I use the "null" function in a bad way?

Comment: `var x= document.getElementById("demo1");
 x = "5.95$";` What do you think the second one is doing? And  you need to learn about if statements and what happens when you do not use `{ }`

Comment: Your markup is also wrong. Ids in the DOM elements must be unique (they can not repeat).

Comment: You're not using curly brackets `{` `}`. If you dont use curly brackets the if statement only executes the next line of code

Comment: so I need to add curly brackets for all my IF statements?

Comment: @bourki Exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `innerHTML` to change the content of a HTML element.

Moreover, you should use a switch to change options, it's much more efficient than rewriting the same code over and over again.

```
function changeit(option) {
    var image;
    var price;

    switch (option) {
    case "salade":
        image = "salade.jpg";
        price = "5.95$";
        break;
    case "escargot":
        image = "escargot.jpg";
        price = "4.95$";
        break;
    case "hidden":
        image = "vile.jpg";
        price = "";
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    document.getElementById("imgselect").setAttribute("src", image);
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = price;
}
```

Comment: Okay I will pimp my code and return with my edit. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Okay so .innerHTML was definately the code I needed and didnt know about. It works like a charm.

Comment: Ive been updating my code with innerhtml and brackets, it does work well. the4kman, ive tried your code and understand it but it doesnt work for me.

Comment: @bourki epascarello edited my answer, it's syntactically correct now; check it out.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks to both. I definately shouldve used switch/break in the first place. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I still posted my edit of the IF statement code with the other peoples answer. (only 1st part of code, for the appetizer huehue